# CHARINDEX always returns zero

Tags: sql, sql-server

Am I stuck or is this a bug or something?

```
declare @text nvarchar = 'ThisTextContainsPandOtherCharacters'
select  charindex(N'P',@text)
```

Its always zero?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length) - you should **always** provide a length for any `varchar` variables and parameters that you use

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have not declared a length for the string, so the default is 1.  Try this:

```
declare @text nvarchar(100) = 'ThisTextContainsPandOtherCharacters';

select  charindex(N'P',@text)
```

Answer (score 1):

Give a length to your variable as below-

```
declare @text nvarchar(200) = 'ThisTextContainsPandOtherCharacters'
select  charindex(N'P',@text)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should declared a length for the string.
please try this

```
DECLARE @text nvarchar(300) = 'ThisTextContainsPandOtherCharacters';

SELECT CHARINDEX(N'P',@text)
```

Answer (score 0):

use size in variable

```
declare @text nvarchar(500) = 'ThisTextContainsPandOtherCharacters'
select  charindex('P',@text)
```